# Notepad++: Mark a word and insert command

Tags: command, notepad++

How can I mark a word in notepad++ and can easily insert a command, with the marked word as argument? E.g.: I have a text with the word `"WORD1"`, I want to mark `"WORD1"` with the mouse, and after press any button/shortcut, or quick contextmenu with the right mouse-button, or anything like that, and it will make it to `"\command{WORD1}"`.

Of course, I want to specify `"\command"`, e.g. I can choose the needed command in a dropdown of the context menu, or choose a specific button/shortcut for any command.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try recording a macro doing what you want and then assigning a keyboard shortcut to it and from then on, you should be able to get it to do what you want.

Look at the `Shortcut Mapper`

[image]

### Finding location of NP++ Macros

Type `%appdata%` in run and hit Enter, when the directory opens, locate Notepad++ and you see `shortcuts.xml`

Comment: That would work, if it was every time the same word. But will it work for every word/expression, too?

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention that when you create the macro using whatever value you want. Close NP++ and then open the macro file inside regular Notepad, search for your macro and then in the place of the variable that you want to be different each time simply change to `%$%` and when you run the marco in the future on x or y or z it will pass that highlighted value to the field and give you the desired effect. The marco system in NP++ is not very intuitive and requires some hacking to make it do what you want but it can be done.

Comment: Alternatively, you can do a bit easier route. Create your macro with say `%REPLACE_ME%` or whatever you want, just make it something that won't come up usually. Then in future codes when you run the macro it will replace it with that. Then do a wild search and replace and put `value_you_want` and replace `whatever you chose to insert with macro` its dirty but also an option, depending on your level of confidence messing with the marco code.

Comment: I will try the first attempt. Where can I find the macro as file, in which directory? After recording the macro I was only asked for a name, not for a place to store it.

Comment: The editor is great but there are tons of stuff about modifying what's not there that is just hard coded into the source. You have to dig the source to see how its done and manipulate it. When it comes to the macros, this might serve as some help hopefully (http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Editing_Configuration_Files#.3CMacros.3E)

Comment: To find the file, you need to look into the data directory of NP++ and you are looking for `shortcut.xml` the location is always default, you can't pick. Also, PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE note that you MUST edit it outside of NP++ and make sure its closed or it will overwrite all your changes with its macro cache. So back up the file, make changes, save it, then copy over the existing one, so you always have your changes. Start it up after you have done that to test the changes. Good luck.

Comment: I have followed your advice. Now I have in the shortcut.xml the macro, but where to add %$% ? Because my variable in the example (while recording) is not there in the file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36309/discussion-between-mustafa-and-gardian)